# Downloading Gitlab-CI artifacts from child pipeline in another child pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am stuck trying to test and deploy micro services in Gitlab-CI. There are many things written about, but no clear example of how to pass on the Database that micro services need to run tests from child to parent to child pipelines.

The database test data and user rights for the micro services are in my case created by a separate projects. So my idea is to use MySQL dump and pump to get the database, plus the user and grant info out using artifacts and import them to the service of all micro service that need to run test.

I started a .gitlab-ci.yml in a separate repro so I could spin of all the micro services from there. Her is a simple .gitlab-ci.yml to show what I intent to do:

```
stages:
  - Database-Creation
  - Database-Security
  - APIs

Product-Tables:
  stage: Database-Creation
  trigger:
    project: 'mircoservices/database/producttables'
    branch: develop
    strategy: depend

Database-Users:
  stage: Database-Security
  trigger:
    project: 'microservices/database/databaseusersandgrants'
    branch: develop
    strategy: depend

Product-API:
  stage: APIs
  trigger:
    project: 'microservices/customers/product'
    branch: develop
    strategy: depend
```

In the .gitlab-ci.yml from *Database-Users* I would need to download the `dump.sql` generated in *Product-Tables*, and in *Product-API* I would need to download both the `dump.sql` from *Product-Tables* and the `users-grants.sql` from *Database-Users* to impost in de MySQL service of that project. The .gitlab-ci.yml of these repros are like so:

*mircoservices/database/producttables/.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
Product-Tables:
  image: serversideup/php:8.2-fpm-nginx

  services:
    - name: mysql:8.0.33-debian
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'sed -i -e "/^skip-name-resolve/d" /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld']
  
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS: "true"
    #FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1

    #mysql variables
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_MICROSERVICE_ADMIN
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_MICROSERVICE_ADMIN_PASSWORD

  script:
    - echo “Create Tables”
    - echo “Seed Tables”

  ################################################
  # Exporting database and making it an artifact #
  ################################################
  after_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y mysql-client
    - mysqldump --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql "$MYSQL_DATABASE" > dump.sql

  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - dump.sql
```

*microservices/database/databaseusersandgrants/.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
Database-Users:
  image: serversideup/php:8.2-fpm-nginx

  services:
    - name: mysql:8.0.33-debian
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'sed -i -e "/^skip-name-resolve/d" /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld']
  
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS: "true"
    #FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1

    #mysql variables
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_MICROSERVICE_ADMIN
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_MICROSERVICE_ADMIN_PASSWORD
  ############# #######################################
  # THIS I HOW I IMAGINE I SHOULD DOWNLOAD AND DEPLOY #
  ##################################################### 
  before_script:
    - 'curl --location --output artifacts.zip "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/microservices%2Fdatabase%2Fproducttables/jobs/artifacts/develop/download?job=Product-Tables&job_token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN"'
    - unzip artifacts.gz
    # import in mysql

  script:
    - echo “create Users”
    - echo “Grant Rights” 

  ################################################
  # Exporting the users and rights and making it an artifact
  ################################################
  after_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y mysql-client
    - mysqlpump -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD --host=mysql --exclude-databases=% --users --exclude-users=root,mysql.sys,mysql.session,mysql.infoschema,microserviceadmin > users-grants.sql

  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - users-grants.sql
```

And then finally in all the micro services I would like to use those artifacts.

*microservices/customers/product*

```
Product-API:
  image: serversideup/php:8.2-fpm-nginx

  services:
    - name: mysql:8.0.33-debian
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'sed -i -e "/^skip-name-resolve/d" /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld']
  
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS: "true"
    #FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1

    #mysql variables
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_MICROSERVICE_ADMIN
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_MICROSERVICE_ADMIN_PASSWORD

  ############# #######################################
  # THIS I HOW I IMAGINE I SHOULD DOWNLOAD AND DEPLOY #
  #####################################################
  before_script:
    - 'curl --location --output db_dump.zip "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/microservices%2Fdatabase%2Fproducttables/jobs/artifacts/develop/download?job=Product-Tables&job_token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN"'
    - 'curl --location --output user-grants.zip "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/microservices%2Fdatabase%2Fdatabaseusersandgrants/jobs/artifacts/develop/download?job=Database-Users&job_token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN"'
    # unzip …
    # mysql < dump.sql and users-grants.sql

  script:
    - echo "Run Tests"
```

The url's that I use in these examples I [found here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html#from-a-url-1) , but they don’t work. I made sure to run successful pipelines in those repro`s before trying this, but no luck.

Then [here I found](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html)  that I can download the artifacts through the use of this

```
'curl --location --output artifacts.zip --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/<job ID>/artifacts"'
```

Now for this to work I would have to pass the id of the two jobs up to the parent pipeline out of *Database-Creation* and *Database-Security* and use them inside the child pipelines where needed. Only I can’t find how to pass on this Job ID from child to parent.

I have been reading and reading and everywhere there are some pieces of the puzzle, but whatever I tried it didn’t work. A clear example of how to pass the Job ID from child to parent and visa versa would be greatly appreciated.

Or maybe an example of how the URL for the last artifacts can be used (but I have given up hope on that one after trying for hours).

Comment: After hours of searching I am starting to fear this is only possible for paid users. An JOB-TOKEN only gives access to that job not jobs in other pipelines. For this you would need a Personal Access Token, but these it looks like you can only generate if you have a paid account..... I might be wrong, the Gitlab documentation is not super clear on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was running into was Authorization related. The `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` is only authorized to access artifacts of the same job/pipeline.

If you want to access artifacts of other pipelines you either need and `Personal Access Token` *(created under user>edit profile then left side menu>Access Tokens)* or a `Group/Project Access Token` *(only available to paid users: in the Group or Project go to the left side menu>Settings>Access Tokens)*.

So as a none paying user I ended up using a *Personal Access Token* that I stored in an *masked variable*. My `curl` command looks something like:

```
 - 'curl --location --output user-grants.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ARTIFACTS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/microservices%2Fdatabase%2Fdatabaseusersandgrants/jobs/artifacts/develop/download?job=Database-Users'
```

*Note:* the `%2F` are there on porous it is the url encoding of a / they should be written like this.